# post Data to API is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post

i want to add one new value to the list from the API,  im fairly new to this.
here is my code

the API response body looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "msisdn": "08282709909013",
    "active": true,
    "remoteSms": "none",
    "default": true
  }
]
```

```
$scope.postAccountMsisdns = function() {
    if (AuthService.isAuth()) {

        AccountMsisdns.one().get().then(
            function(accountmsisdn) {
                accountmsisdn.data = newMsisdn;
                accountmsisdn.data.post();
            }

        );
    }
};



var getAccountMsisdns = function() {
    if (AuthService.isAuth()) {
        // check only when authenticated (or refresh possible)
        AccountMsisdns.one().get().then(
            function(resultOk) {
                $log.d("AccountMsisdns ok: ", resultOk);
                $scope.accountmsisdn = resultOk.data;
            },
            function(resultError) {
                $log.d("AccountMsisdns error: ", resultError);
                ErrorService.showApiError(resultError);
            },
            function(resultNotify) {
                $log.d("AccountMsisdns notify:", resultNotify);
            }
        );
    }
};
getAccountMsisdns();
```

here the html:

```
<div>       
    <p> <input type="text" ng-model="newMsisdn.msisdn"> neue msisdn  {{newMsisdn.msisdn}}
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="newMsisdn.active"> active  {{newMsisdn.active}}
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="newMsisdn.remoteSms"> neue remoteSms  {{newMsisdn.remoteSms}}
    <p><input type="text"ng-model="newMsisdn.default"> neue default  {{newMsisdn.default}}
</div>
<button ng-click="postAccountMsisdns()">UpdatePost</button>
```

Comment: Whats your question/problem?

Comment: postAccountMsisdns is useless, this code must be faulty, because no post order is performed

Comment: Well you can't just append `.post()` to some object and expect javascript to know where to post it.^^ Use some angular services like `$http` or `$resource` to create your post function.

Comment: this is defined in another factory,  so put and get are working in another functions, but post isnt doing what i want it to do..^^

Comment: Maybe you should post your code from `AccountMsisdns`. Without we can't do much.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort!  i found the problem - posting to the API is not allowed hahaha.. ;)